# Grafana: How to assign environment variable to http_port

Tags: grafana

I am trying to run grafana but i need to specify the port using an environment variable. Currently, in the `custom.ini` i have

```
# The http port  to use
http_port = 9082
```

how do i assign an environment variable to http_port ? It would be best if i could do it from the command line but the only command line options available are

```
Usage of bin\grafana-server.exe:
  -config string
        path to config file
  -homepath string
        path to grafana install/home path, defaults to working directory
  -pidfile string
        path to pid file
  -v    prints current version and exits
```

is there any way to assign an environment variable to the http_port?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Windows user but I guess you can write a script (bat?) to first generate the `custom.ini` file filling `http_port` with an environment variable, then run `grafana-server.exe` pointing to the generated config file.